# Pandas: calculate the climatology anomalies for daily data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe of daily data as shown below:

```
gpi_data['sig']
Out[34]: 
2007-01-02   -8.963545
2007-01-03   -8.671357
2007-01-03   -8.996480
2007-01-04   -8.835958
2007-01-05   -8.785034
  
2019-12-28   -8.328209
2019-12-29   -8.380242
2019-12-30   -8.532246
2019-12-30   -8.532573
2019-12-31   -8.345356
Name: sig, Length: 6368, dtype: float32
```

Then I want to calculate the climatology anomalies for the variable `sig`. Say, for data in `2007-01-02`, I need to calculate the `mean` values of DOY (day of year) `01-02` on year of `2007`,`2008`,...,`2019`. Say the average value is `X`, the "climatology anomalies" is defined as `-8.963545 - X`. So how can I do that?

I just know that I can use `gpi_data.groupby(gpi_data.index.dayofyear).mean()` as shown below to calculate `X` values on each DOY.

```
1     -8.811016
2     -8.693721
3     -8.550734
4     -8.642129
5     -8.565906
  
362   -8.611540
363   -8.619987
364   -8.574184
365   -8.794723
366   -8.829847
Name: sig, Length: 366, dtype: float32
```

but how can I match each time stamp in `gpi_data` to the DOY? say to match data `2007-01-02   -8.963545` to DOY `2 -8.693721`? Thanks!

---

And I am wondering, if I got the anomalies predicted by a model, say `gpi_data_predicted`, how can I add the anomalies to the original climatology to "denormalize" the data to get the final results? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.transform('mean')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
gpi_data['sig'].sub(gpi_data.groupby(pd.to_datetime(gpi_data.index).dayofyear)
                    ['sig'].transform('mean'))
```

Output:

```
2007-01-02    0.000000
2007-01-03    0.162561
2007-01-03   -0.162562
2007-01-04    0.000000
2007-01-05    0.000000
2019-12-28    0.000000
2019-12-29    0.000000
2019-12-30    0.000163
2019-12-30   -0.000163
2019-12-31    0.000000
Name: sig, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And how can I do the inverse way? say if I got an anomalies and a climatology mean, how can I add them together so that I can get the original time series?

Comment: @XuShan not sure what you mean, the sum of the anomalies should be 0 (per dayofyear), no?

Comment: no, I mean sum of anomalies and climatology, to get the original time series

Comment: if you kept the output of the `transform('mean')`, add it back, else there is no way

Comment: ah ok, so how can I do the "add"? thanks!

Comment: Step1: `avg = gpi_data.groupby(pd.to_datetime(gpi_data.index).dayofyear)['sig'].transform('mean') ; out = gpi_data['sig'].sub(avg)` step2: `original = out+avg`?

Comment: ah yes, thanks, I think maybe pd.add also do the similar things?

Comment: Yes `out.add(avg)` would do the same thing